# ios Settings Bundle creates 2 group headers when specifying only 1

Tags: ios, ios-settings-bundle

I have created a Settings.bundle file in my iOS project.

When I create the following group, it automatically creates another header above it called "App Settings"  where App is the name of the Xcode Project.

[image]

On my app, it creates a header above "Push Registration Settings" called App Settings.

Any ideas where this other group header is coming from?

Comment: That heading gets added by iOS when you provide a settings bundle.

Comment: Yeah. But, I don't understand when you specify a specific group heading... how can I get rid of the default one that iOS adds.

Comment: You can't. It will always be there to separate any system settings for your app (location, camera access etc) from your app settings. Your groups come under the app settings.